# hello weird 310. too many redirects error

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect

bellow is my htaccess file. the thing is on my shop page patutbebe.ro top right of the page is the log in/register button for the clients. when you press this button it gives you the upmentioned error. I tried changing from the wordpress settings the siteurl and home but they were correct, i tryed the time and date sync, i tryed the cookies and popup bloker thing in google chrome. i tryed also the plugin for canonical links(remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical')still nada. if you have any ideeas of whats going on please help me. im new in this and this is my first site.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^pat\-sertar\-clasic\.php$ "http\:\/\/patutbebe\.ro\/shop\/copii\/patut\-cu\-sertar\-si\-leganare\/clasic\-patut\-cu\-sertar\-si\-leganare\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

so i kind of solved the problem with that one... i made a new page in wordpress deleted the new one, not permanent because i want to see more into it. but now i have quota problems and i phink because 90% of quota disk space on my ftp is used  my woocommerce plugin wont work properly. everythime i want to put something in the cart it doesnt aply. the cart remaines empty